# php decrypting base64Encoding text from iOS

Tags: php, ios, encryption, base64

I have spent a huge amount of time with no success trying to decrypt an encrypted string (`"yIH7EYW0e4HuxkHApkG7xQ=="`) on the PHP server side. The string was encrypted on iOS platform and encoded into text using base64 format.

Anyway, could someone please correct my mistake with the PHP side (I am a little weak on this side)? I am aware the method is not very secure as is. I just need a temporary solution until I can research better methods with openssl.

---

PHP:

```
$str_encrypted = "yIH7EYW0e4HuxkHApkG7xQ=="; // base64encoded
$mykey = "my password";
$decrypted = decrypt_data($str_encrypted =, $mykey);

function decrypt_data($str_encrypted =, $mykey)
{
  $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
  $decrypted_text = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $encryptionkey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
  return $decrypted_text;
}
```

---

IOS:

```
- (NSString *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{

    NSData *plainData = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *encryptedData = [plainData AES128EncryptWithKey:key];

    NSString *encryptedString = [encryptedData base64Encoding];

    return encryptedString;

}
```

IOS:

```
- (NSString *)base64Encoding
{
   const unsigned char *bytes = [self bytes];
   NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:self.length];
   unsigned long ixtext = 0;
   unsigned long lentext = self.length;
   long ctremaining = 0;
   unsigned char inbuf[3], outbuf[4];
   unsigned short i = 0;
   unsigned short charsonline = 0, ctcopy = 0;
   unsigned long ix = 0;

   while( YES )
   {
      ctremaining = lentext - ixtext;
      if( ctremaining <= 0 ) break;

      for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
      {
         ix = ixtext + i;
         if( ix < lentext ) inbuf[i] = bytes[ix];
         else inbuf [i] = 0;
      }

      outbuf [0] = (inbuf [0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
      outbuf [1] = ((inbuf [0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((inbuf [1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
      outbuf [2] = ((inbuf [1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((inbuf [2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
      outbuf [3] = inbuf [2] & 0x3F;
      ctcopy = 4;

      switch( ctremaining )
      {
         case 1:
            ctcopy = 2;
            break;
         case 2:
            ctcopy = 3;
            break;
      }

      for( i = 0; i < ctcopy; i++ )
         [result appendFormat:@"%c", encodingTable[outbuf[i]]];

      for( i = ctcopy; i < 4; i++ )
         [result appendString:@"="];

      ixtext += 3;
      charsonline += 4;

   }

   return [NSString stringWithString:result];
}
```

Comment: How do you want to decrypt Base64-encoded text using Rijndael-128?

Comment: I want to get the original message from it so I can process it on the webserver (where php resides).  Text is encrypted on iOS but needs to be decrypted on the webserver.

Comment: @kindkoder Is the original data `POG` followed by 13 carriage returns?

Comment: @kindkoder you have to base64-decode the string in the PHP script first, only then pass it to the Rijndael decryption.

Comment: @DaveRandom it should only be POG nothing else, I guess the 13 carriage returns are introduced artifacts!.  Well sounds like you are able to decrypt it.  Can you share teh PHP code?

Comment: @H2CO3 how do I base64 decode it? -- tia

Comment: I got it!  base64_decode().  Never thought I am so dumb sometimes!  Thanks everybody!  Should have posted earlier instead of spending all that time.

Comment: @kindkoder You should still check this: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VqEAN9

Comment: @DaveRandom .  I think it's probably from the - (NSString *)base64Encoding method that I blindly copied.  I just pasted it in the original message (see above).  If you recall what I alluded to earlier, this encryption scheme is full of holes.  But it will do for now to get approval to continue with the project, and give me time to implement something more secure.

Comment: Hi new user & welcome. You don't need an IV when performing (unsafe) ECB mode decryption. Furthermore, on decryption using CBC mode, it does not make sense to use a random IV, you should use the same IV used during encryption.